# GraphViz Javascript : ReferenceError: "Viz" is undefined

Tags: javascript, graphviz

I am getting the following error when i am trying to use the viz.js in IE9.

ReferenceError: "Viz" is undefined

Any ideas ?

Comment: Please post a sample with more details.  Does it work in other browsers but not in IE?

Comment: It works in Chrome and FF and also in IE 10 and above. There is a discussion here but i couldnt get a corrected js. https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js/issues/16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Vis.js doesn't work in IE9.  I tested the examples page at http://mdaines.github.io/viz.js/example.html and that doesn't work in IE9.  Take a look at using [d3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3), [dagre-d3](https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre-d3) and [graphlib-dot](https://github.com/cpettitt/graphlib-dot) instead, I have confirmed that combination works in IE9.

The Javascript to render Graphviz using graphlib-dot looks like this:

```
var g = graphlibDot.parse(
    'digraph {\n' +
    '    g77 [label="Jesus"];' +
    '    g76 [label="Joseph"];' +
    '    g77 -> g76 [label="SON OF"];' +
    '    }'
)
var renderer = new dagreD3.Renderer();
renderer.run(g, d3.select("svg g"));
```

See a full example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/richardneish/x5SP3/).

Comment: I tried but nothing is rendering . I am getting the following error       
      ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
      renderer.run(g, d3.select("svg g"));

I have all the required js files

Comment: Cool... I got it working. using d3.v3.min.js. I am able to render graphs in IE9 as well... 
Thank you Richard...

Comment: Any idea how can i define auto width and height to SVG ?

Comment: Also how to change the color of the edge(arrow) on the fly. 
'Label2 -> Label13[color="red"]' is not working for me. It takes the default css color

Comment: what about the edge path coloring ? I am trying to make few edge red

Comment: Hi Richard, Any help on above ?

Comment: No, I don't know how to style individual edges.  It looks possible, since the demo at http://cs.brown.edu/people/jcmace/d3/graph.html?id=small.json colors edges when you click on a node.  Try asking that as a separate question!